# Salesforce CLI Deprecated environment variable SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, node.js, powershell

G'day,

I'm following the [trailhead guide for visual code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/use-vscode-for-salesforce)

**SF CLI Version**: @salesforce/cli/1.79.0 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0

**Windows Version**: 10 20H2 OS 19042.2965.

**Visual Code Version**: 2023-05-10 1.78.2

**PowerShell Version**: 7.3.4

When I run the following command (or any any other)

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias VSCodePlayground --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

This results in the output window displaying the following warning that I can't resolve.

> (node:21356) Warning: Deprecated environment variable: SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT. Please use SF_JSON_TO_STDOUT instead. (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

How do I remove this warning?

- There are no references to SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT https://github.com/salesforcecli to this specific warning so I assume it's a NodeJS behavior or configuration problem.
- There is a reference to SF_JSON_TO_STDOUT  https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/blob/2edfa91f9e0119000053f3a3aaf2012ba4d14446/src/config/envVars.ts#L75 in the repository, it's just not obvious if those environment variables should exist in my windows profile (non admin user). I have none listed `$env:SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT` and `$env:SF_JSON_TO_STDOUT` have no results
- I've run `sf update` with no change in behaviour
- I've automated the installation of [Salesforce CLI via Chocolatey](https://github.com/zcassels/sfdx-chocolatey-installer/compare/master...Jamie-Clayton:sfdx-chocolatey-installer:master) and submitted a PR to bring it up to date.
- It looks like the sfdx output in Powershell environments is not rendering to the output windows. This may be exaggerated by long environment variable PATH issues in on my developer workstation that required manual intervention via https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491667/342719 as SQL Server
- There is no Windows Environment Variable SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT listed